# Most efficient way of selecting current, previous and next values of and item in SQLite

Tags: php, sql, performance, sqlite

Currently I have a page displaying 2 images on the left and right side with php and SQLite.

With a given image id I query for

- the file for that image
- the file  for the next-image
- the link to the next-next-image
- the link to the prev-prev-image
- the link to the prev-image (in case prev-prev does not exist)

I have tried using offsets, however it seems that the whole query fails if my offset is out of bounds, is there any way to prevent or catch that?

```
select id, file, findex
  from vfb
 where findex > (select findex from vfb where findex<4 and bookcode='BEFB'
                 order by findex desc limit 1 offset 1)
   and findex < (select findex from vfb where findex>4 and bookcode='BEFB'
                 order by findex asc limit 1 offset 1)
   and bookcode='BEFB'
 order by findex asc;
```

Now I am using the `select(select a where x<1) as a1, (select a where x=1) as b1, (select b where x=1) as c1` structure, which is very ugly and it turns out I now need need more information from the query like (`select a where x<1`).

So, is there a way to shorten my query and or use something like `(select a,b where x<1) as a1,b2`?

My table is like `Id|bookcode|page|findex(fakepage)|file|title|stuff|morestuff`

Full ugly select:

```
select 
(select findex from vfb where bookcode='BOOK' and findex<
    (select findex from vfb where bookcode='BOOK' and findex<100 order by findex desc limit 1) order by findex desc limit 1) as p2,
(select findex from vfb where bookcode='BOOK' and findex<100 order by findex desc limit 1) as p1,
(select file from vfb where bookcode='BOOK' and findex==100) as f1,
(select file from vfb where bookcode='BOOK' and findex>100 order by findex asc limit 1) as f2,
(select findex from vfb where bookcode='BOOK' and findex>
    (select findex from vfb where bookcode='BOOK' and findex>100 order by findex asc limit 1) order by findex asc limit 1) as n2;
```

Results In:
`98|99|BOOK_Page_104_Image_0001.png|BOOK_Page_105_Image_0001.png|102`

I have tried using offsets, however it seems that the whole query fails if my offset is out of bounds, is there anyway to prevent or catch that?

Comment: Does SQLite support windows functions? (`lag()`, `lead()` would make this a piece of cake)

Comment: I do not know, SQLite is multiplatform though.

Comment: how large a table are we dealing with here?

Answer (score 1):

Nice riddle, I have considered only findex field.
Please try:

```
  SELECT t3.findex , t2.findex, t4.findex
    FROM vfb t1
    JOIN vfb t2 ON t1.findex > t2.findex
    JOIN vfb t3 ON t2.findex > t3.findex
    JOIN vfb t4 ON t1.findex < t4.findex
    WHERE
    t1.findex = 100
    AND t1.bookcode='BOOK' 
    AND t2.bookcode='BOOK' 
    AND t3.bookcode='BOOK'
    AND t4.bookcode='BOOK'
    ORDER by t3.findex desc, t2.findex desc, t4.findex asc
    LIMIT 1
```

If above is working please consider add index on findex column. GL!

Comment: I realized too and and am too lazy to redo the table, but yes each entry has a 'real' index and a 'fake'index that is based on the book, ideally I think each book should have been it's own table perhaps.

I ended up going a PHP heavy way and doing 2 queries like findex>=100 limit 3

Comment: Common. You want the easiest (but efficient) path. But nice work!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a PHP heavy implementation since that was what I was working with. I had two queries which ended up being like:

```
$result = $db->query('select * from vfb where findex<=
(select findex from vfb where id=222)
and bookcode=(select bookcode from vfb where id=222)
group by page order by findex desc limit 3');
```

This gets the current item and the next two below it. The same can be done for the above items. I then used PHP to get the desired values.